# What's the acceptable range for reg_alpha and reg_lambda in H2O XGboost?

Tags: h2o

H2O document doesn't detail on these two hyper parameters. It only says these are L1 and L2 regularization parameters, with default values as 0 and 1. I can't find more info googling it either. Can someone provide any insight?  TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Alpha and lambda have no acceptable range. Usually, it depends on the problem you're trying to solve and the other parameters you're using, like max depth. The value for both typically ranges from 0 to 5, but it is not limited to that range.

I recommend you to take a look at this link: https://medium.com/data-design/xgboost-hi-im-gamma-what-can-i-do-for-you-and-the-tuning-of-regularization-a42ea17e6ab6

The idea is very clearly explained.